# How to multiply values in a column stored in a variable in measure up to the point in a corresponding column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure which contains a variable table that has "days column" and another "percentages column" I need to display the multiplication of the percentages column on a line chart x-axis is the days and y-axis is the multiplication of the percentages up to the current dates
I have tried this code

```
M_kaplan_meier_first_selected = 
var first_selected_MDR=MIN(BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet[MDR_lookups])

// calculate all patients that started the study


var all_=CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet[PATIENT_ID]),ALL(BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet[dayss]),
   BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet[dayss]<>BLANK(),BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet[MDR_lookups]=first_selected_MDR)


// to create a table with the follwing equation 1-(dead daily patients/(all patients-censored))

var dead_selected=CALCULATE([M_dead_daily],BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet[MDR_lookups]=first_selected_MDR)

var discharged_selected=CALCULATE([m_totaldischarged],BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet[MDR_lookups]=first_selected_MDR)

var kaplan=
CALCULATETABLE(
    SUMMARIZE(BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet,BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet[dayss]
    ,"k",
    1-DIVIDE(dead_selected,all_-discharged_selected)),
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED(BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet),
    BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet[dayss]<MAX(BacteriologyRegistry_Whonet[dayss])))

// to multiply the percentage calculated in the above table till the selected date 
var prod=
PRODUCTX(kaplan,[k])
return prod
```

please note that I have check all the results of the variables they are all correct expect the multiplication in the end which the productx function

[image: this is the expected]

[image: while this is what I have]

Just to give a small back ground the number starts with 1 and the least it can be is 0 and it is only allowed to get lower not higher since it is a survival analysis so people who die get get back to life

Comment: Please paste code as text with the correct markdown format instead of images. The problem may be clear to you, but it isn't well described to us. Breakdown the issue for us so we can try to help.

Comment: Thank you for your comment I have amended the code is it clearer now?

Comment: Can you share why the multiplication with `PRODUCTX` is incorrect? What values are you getting and what values are you expecting? Thus far, nothing is popping up in your code that could be an issue.

Comment: I have edited the original post and added a picture from the internet to what in general this graph looks like it starts at 1 in the Y-axis and keep going over time down to 0 and the value on the y-axis at some point in time can't exceed a previous point since it is the ratio of people who survived to the people that are still alive so the people just die they don't get back to life

Comment: Please create a new Calculated Table with the same code as above, but change the `return` to `return kaplan`. Validate the values in this table, I think you'll spot the issue.

Comment: you mean I need to create a physical table with my summarize ?
I have created separated measures for every single variable I have and for the ratio I have and reflected it on a table it was all correct except the multiplication

Comment: My suggestion is for debugging purposes only. Create the table, have a look at it and validate the valus for `k`.

Answer (score 0):

I used python script visual to solve the issue with the following code
the commented is left there in case you want to add multiple lines on same graph

```
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(dayss, M_kaplan_meier_first_selected, M_kaplan_meier_second_selected)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

# Paste or type your script code here:
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x1 = pd.DataFrame(dataset["M_kaplan_meier_first_selected"])
#x2 = pd.DataFrame(dataset["M_kaplan_meier_second_selected"])
y1= x1.cumprod()
#y2= x2.cumprod()

plt.plot(dataset["dayss"], y1)
#plt.plot(dataset["dayss"], y2)

plt.ylim(0, 1)

#plt.legend(['M_kaplan_meier_first_selected', 'M_kaplan_meier_second_selected'], loc='upper center')
plt.show()
```